# NSLog content of uint32_t array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, arrays

I'm working with another programmer on some code. He has written a decoding algorithm in C, and provided me with an Objective-c class the serves as a wrapper to avoid me to have to handle calls to his code.

His .h file looks like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "decode_audio_data.h"


@interface DecoderWrapper : UIViewController {
    uint32_t   numberOfDecodedData; 
    uint32_t   decodedData[MAX_DECODED_DATA_SIZE]; 
}


- (void) feedData:(int16_t [])data;
- (uint32_t) numberOfDecodedData;
- (uint32_t *) decodedData;


@end
```

Now, I'm calling without problem both "feedData" and "numberOfDecodedData" functions, but I'm facing some problems to call "decodedData", that it's supposed to return an array of uint32_t.

How do I NSLog the content of that array? I'm pretty confused because I don't know C and I'm not very confident with pointers....

This is the point where I'm doing the calls:

```
[decoderWrapped feedData:debug];

if ([decoderWrapped numberOfDecodedData] > 0) {
    for (in j=0; j<[decoderWrapped numberOfDecodedData]; j++) {
        // how do I print out every position of [decoderWrapped decodedData] ??

    }   
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSLog(@"%u", [decoderWrapped decodedData][j]);
```

inside of your loop you've got so far.

Comment: OMG, was it that simple? shame on me

Comment: Depending on what the data is supposed to be, `%x` may be more useful (cc @Sr.Richie)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is `NSLog( @"%d", [[decoderWrapped decodedData][j] )`. A `uint32_t` is really just an `unsigned int` ([related - `typedef`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)).

The longer answer is you would want to have a look at the [string formatting guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), which is almost identical to [C-string formatting](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output), with some additions to handle objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
    uint32_t *decodedData = [decoderWrapped decodedData];
    for (int j=0; j<12; j++) {
        NSLog(@"%d",decodedData[j]);
    }
```